# How to use ^[]$ format to compare string with numbers greater than 9?

Tags: bash

Say I have a simple statement:

```
read number

[[ ! $number =~ ^[1-3245][,][1-3245]$ ]] && echo "Not a valid number."
```

I want to check to see if the number is between 1-3245. But it seems like it's looking for a number between 1 and 3 for the first integer, then 2,4,5. How do get this to check if the number entered looks like 1-3245,1-3245? I've tried with {} and .. instead of -
But still no go. I'd like to avoid a crazy long string .

*Edit
I should be more specific here. I am looking to check user input and match it to a desired format; that format being 'int,int,int....' where int is = an integer between 1-3245. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The expression `[1-3245]`  is simply a different way of saying `[123245]`, which is a redundant way to say `[12345]`, and more concisely could also have been written simply as `[1-5]`. For instance, if you read the number `2,2`, the regex will match and you will see the output _Not a valid number_. For checking the numerical value of a number, use a regex to see, whether the variable syntactically **is** a number, and then use arithmetic comparision to test its value.

Comment: What is a _number between 1-3245_? Is it a number between `1` and `3245`? And what is a _number that looks like `1-3245,1-3245`_? A fractional number with integer and fractional parts between `1` and `3245` and a comma as separator?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, IMHO `I want to check to see if the number is between 1-3245` is stated by OP, so mostly it's between 1 to 3245 only, though it occured to me also by seeing OPs efforts but then by above mentioned line by OP it got clear to me, cheers.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet its simply any integer between 1 and 3245.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your criteria is: integer between 1 and 3245 (included), comma, integer between 1 and 3245 (included), you can use a mixture of regular expression and arithmetic:

```
$ foo() {
  [[ "$1" =~ ^([0-9]*),([0-9]*)$ ]] || return 1
  a=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; b=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  (( a >= 1 && a <= 3245 && b >= 1 && b <= 3245 ))
}
$ foo 2,2 && echo "OK" || echo "Not a valid number."
OK
$ foo 2,4000 && echo "OK" || echo "Not a valid number."
Not a valid number.
$ foo 2,bar
Not a valid number.
```

If the number of comma-separated integers is unknown (but minimum one) and you want to use only `bash`you will need a loop:

```bash
$ foo() {
  n="$1"
  while [[ "$n" =~ ^([0-9]+)((,[0-9]+)*)$ ]]; do
    (( BASH_REMATCH[1] < 1 || BASH_REMATCH[1] > 3245 )) && return 1
    n="${BASH_REMATCH[2]#,}"
    [[ -z "$n" ]] && return 0
  done
  return 1
}
$ foo 2,2,2,2,2 && echo "OK" || echo "Not a valid number."
OK
$ foo 2,2,4000,2,2 && echo "OK" || echo "Not a valid number."
Not a valid number.
$ foo 2,2,bar,2,2 && echo "OK" || echo "Not a valid number."
Not a valid number.
```

But if you can also use external utilities GNU `awk` would be a bit simpler:

```bash
$ foo() {
  awk -F, 'NR > 1 { exit 1 } {
    for(i=1; i<NF; i++)
      if($i !~ /^[0-9]+$/ || $i < 1 || $i > 3245) exit 1
  }' <<< "$1"
}
$ foo 2,2,2,2,2 && echo "OK" || echo "Not a valid number."
OK
$ foo 2,2,4000,2,2 && echo "OK" || echo "Not a valid number."
Not a valid number.
$ foo 2,2,2,bar,2 && echo "OK" || echo "Not a valid number."
Not a valid number.
```

Comment: So I tried out your code and it works. Thanks a million. Can you explain the 3rd line where 'a' and 'b' are defined?? I'm lost in that.

Comment: replacing the $ with + allows for a continuous series of numbers. BUT any number after b is not checked. Anyhow, this has been very helpful along with all the other responses. Wish I could add a check to all of them.

Comment: `BASH_REMATCH` is a bash array that stores the results of the previous `[[ x =~ y ]]`. It stores the matched string (index 0) and the captured groups (a capture group is represented by a parenthesized sub-expression in the regular expression). See `man bash`for the details.

Comment: I just saw your edit and updated my answer to support any number (at least 1) of comma-separated integers.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, ++ve for nice solution. I too thought for this, since OP confirmed my regex was working for OP so didn't this, this will be more helpful, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

Since the base question is to write on regex to get range of numbers. So keeping it as my first solution here, for future readers help.

***1st solution(using regex):*** With your shown samples and attempts you can have your bash script like as follows, please make sure to give script proper permissions and run it then.

Also here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/gAFGfs/1) for used regex.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter a number:"
read number

if [[ $number =~ ^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2[0-9]{3}|[3][0-1][0-9]{2}|32[0-3][0-9]|324[0-5])$ ]]
then
    echo "Number $number is between 1 to 3245"
else
    echo "Please enter number in range of 1 to 3245..."
fi
```

***Explanation:***

- Firstly printing message on screen by `echo` command for user, its always a Good practice to put a proper user-friendly message on screen. Here in this case its "Please enter a number:"
- Using `read` command to get value from user and save it into `number` shell variable.
- Then using `if` condition to match value of variable with regex`^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2[0-9]{3}|[3][0-1][0-9]{2}|32[0-3][0-9]|324[0-5])$`, remember bash doesn't support non-capturing groups here.
- if condition is TRUE then print eg: `Number 2980 is between 1 to 3245` else print eg: `Please enter number in range of 1 to 3245...`

---

---

***2nd solution:*** using `awk` and without regex here.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter a number:"
read number

val=$(echo $number | awk '$0+0==$0 && ($0>=1 && $0<=3245)')

if [[ -n "$val"  ]]
then
    echo "Number $number is between 1 to 3245"
else
    echo "Please enter number in range of 1 to 3245..."
fi
```

Comment: I figured I could do something like that, but I desperately wanted to avoid making long strings. I used a very modest example for numbers I am actually using. Thank you though.

Comment: @dvines, ok Good to know. Have you tried my code? Could you please do let me know what you figured out and what solution you used, since I spent sometime on this one, so wanted to know, cheers.

Comment: @dvines, ok, in case you don't want to use big regex(which will be the case here) then try my 2nd solution without regex one.

Comment: @dvines Regular expressions don't really "know" anything about numbers, just sequences of characters (and digits are, for regex purposes, just ordinary characters with no special meaning). Trying to do math via regex is possible, but inherently clumsy because it's so foreign to what regex is about. You're really better off using tools that actually understand numbers (like the `awk` solution here).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I will let you know later today when I get some time :) I haven't tried anything yet. Thank you to everyone for responding.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 so your 2nd solution works as far as validating whether or not the input is between the desired numbers. But I need to check the format of the input i.e. does the input look like a series of numbers: 1,2,3,4 where each number is between a desired value (example 1-3245). I hope I am making sense here.

Comment: @dvines, sure you want to combine both the conditions OR have both the conditions in same program right?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the first solution doesn't work either because it expects an input of '0' after the first int i.e 324 doesn't work because of [0-5] where an empty space isn't accepted.

Comment: @dvines, ok I have fixed my regex now, please try this once `^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{3}|2[0-9]{3}|[3][0-1][0-9]{2}|32[0-3][0-9]|324[0-5])$` It was tested in https://regex101.com/r/iyBr7G/1  let me know how it goes. Will update my answer also. Adding one more link where same regex but tested more digits: https://regex101.com/r/gAFGfs/1

Comment: @dvines, Please test this newly updated codes(regex) and let me know how it goes and then we can discuss if you want to add both the conditions(1st check integer with regex and 2nd compare it with awk etc), let me know how it goes, I tested and things look Good to me with updated one.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yup! it works like a charm! No need for the awk, this one works great. Thanks a million.